# How can I combine two queries with a having clause into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I hope you can help me with these two queries query:

```
select count(distinct ID), sum(AMOUNT) 
from SALES 
where YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' and SALETYPE ='CASH'
group by CUSTOMER having sum(AMOUNT) >=500;

select count(distinct ID), sum(AMOUNT) 
from SALES 
where YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' and SALETYPE ='CREDITCARD'
group by CUSTOMER having sum(AMOUNT) >=1000;
```

What is the best way to combine them into one? My aim is to select all cases where a CUSTOMER paid more than 500 in CASH OR more than 1000 via CREDITCARD.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use this example:

```
select  count(distinct ID), 
        sum(AMOUNT) 
from    SALES 
where   YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' 
    and SALETYPE ='CASH' 
group by CUSTOMER 
having  sum(AMOUNT) >=500;

UNION

select  count(distinct ID), 
        sum(AMOUNT) 
from    SALES 
where   YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' 
    and SALETYPE ='CREDITCARD' 
group by CUSTOMER 
having  sum(AMOUNT) >=1000;
```

OR UNION ALL if you want all records without **distinct**.

```
select  count(distinct ID), 
        sum(AMOUNT) 
from    SALES 
where   YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' 
    and SALETYPE ='CASH' 
group by CUSTOMER 
having  sum(AMOUNT) >=500;

UNION ALL

select  count(distinct ID), 
        sum(AMOUNT) 
from    SALES 
where   YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' 
        and SALETYPE ='CREDITCARD' 
group by CUSTOMER 
having  sum(AMOUNT) >=1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
select count(distinct ID), sum(AMOUNT) 
from SALES 
where YEAR(SALEDATE) = '2015' and 
      SALETYPE IN ('CASH', 'CREDITCARD')
group by CUSTOMER
having sum(case when SALETYPE = 'CASH' then AMOUNT end) >= 50 OR
       sum(case when SALETYPE = 'CREDITCARD' then AMOUNT end) >= 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your book also looks useful.
However, shouldn't it be OR instead of AND?

`having sum(case when SALETYPE = 'CASH' then AMOUNT end) >= 50 OR(!)
       sum(case when SALETYPE = 'CREDITCARD' then AMOUNT end) >= 1000;`

Comment: @user1269766 . . . Yes.  I had read the question as wanting both conditions filled.